# How can i print on a new line without skipping?

Tags: python

I have a bit of code from a class which prints a line, and every line is followed by an empty line.
Is there a way to adjust the following code so that I don't have to have those empty lines?

```
def bfield(self):
    self.n=0
    for i in self.whole:
        for j in i:
            print("{:>4}".format(j), end='')
            self.n=self.n+1
            if self.n==len(i):
                print('\n')
                self.n=0
```

Comment: try removing print('\n')

Comment: The hard question would be how to print on a line and stay on that line (you wouldn't use `print`) - print automatically adds a line ending, so you don't have to print one yourself with `print('\n')`

Comment: ('\n') is usually used to create a new line in a paragraph or a phrase giving you a some kind of control over the output string. Just like Rahul & Grismar mentioned above, in your case, there is no need to specify a newline ('\n') since you'll automatically get a newline at the end of each print statement. 

For example - 

print("Hello world, this is just an example. '\n' But the result is"+resultvariable)

and

    print("Hello world, this is just an example.")
    print("But the result is"+resultvariable)

Same output in both scenario

Answer (score 1):

I'll agree with Rahul Chowdhury, remove the \n. Pythons print command, by default, will always start a new line after each print call. Hence your addition of '\n' will always result in an empty line.

If you wanted to look into how to get around the whole newline thing python does (every call in its own line), I found this [link](https://www.stechies.com/python-print-without-newline/) for you. It is fairly simple to do!

EDIT: It just occurred to me I should maybe list a few of the options just in case the link goes down. Here is one example:

```
print("Hello ", end = '')
print("World!")
```

With this, you overwrite the usual python lineend with your end = '' argument.

Another option would be to use the sys library

```
import sys
```

and then call the stdout.write() function, like so:

```
sys.stdout.write("Hello ")
sys.stdout.write("World!")
```